# what is sql query of below table?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE table1(kid char(2),color varchar(9));

INSERT INTO table1('k1'.'yello');
INSERT INTO table1('k1'.'red');
INSERT INTO table1('k2'.'yello');
INSERT INTO table1('k2'.'blue');
INSERT INTO table1('k3'.'yello');
```

Q: Display `kid` of table1 which has `color` values yellow and red (both of them)?

What is sql query?

Comment: yes123 voted for not a real question

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.kid
    FROM TABLE1 t
   WHERE t.color IN ('yellow', 'red')
GROUP BY t.kid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.color) = 2
```

- The `IN` clause will get only records whose `color` values are either yellow or red
- The `GROUP BY` is necessary to remove duplicates
- `COUNT(DISTINCT t.color) = 2` ensures valid `kid` values will be returned.  Without the `DISTINCT`, two yellows/etc would satisfy the `COUNT` check

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT kid 
  FROM table1 as t, 
       table1 as t2 
 WHERE t1.color = 'yellow' 
   AND t1.kid = t2.kid 
   AND t2.color = 'red'
```